# C# Entity Update-Database says it completes, but it doesn't

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm pretty unsure what's happening here. Any time I run `Update-Database` I get the successful `Running Seed method.` when I'm finished. However, when I go to the `__MigrationHistory` (or look for the added columns), nothing changed. This happens when I use `-TargetMigration` as well. No matter what I do, the database isn't getting modified.

I'm not even sure what other info I can include to help narrow down the solution. Any tips?

Edit - Forgot to mention that I've run with the `-Verbose` flag and the connection is the same one I am currently using in Server Explorer.

Comment: Start with `Update-Database –Verbose` and get more info. Check the connection string being used. Have you run migrations before? Also could use -Script to see what EF is going to apply.

Comment: Ahh, forgot to mention I did that. It's using what I have setup as `DefaultConnection` (which is the same as what I use in ServerExplorer). I've run numerous migrations before. This queries look good too...

Comment: If you run `update-database -Script` does it contain the expected changes? You can also add `Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);` to your context constructor to make sure EF is actually using what you expect.

Comment: `-Script` gives me what I would expect. The connection string is different than I would expect, but I believe it to be correct. It returns `Target database is: 'DefaultConnection' (DataSource: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).` Which isn't what I expected (I thought it would return the details from `<connectionStrings`, not from `<entityFramework>` (neither of which have changed from the previous migration).

Comment: Try forcing your desired connection string: `Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "MyConnectionString"`

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I've been beating my head against a brick wall because of this issue. `-ConnectionStringName` didn't fix it, but it got me on the right track and I ended up specifying the `-ConnectionString` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156387/discussion-between-matt-and-steve-greene).